# How do I get the current Y of a certain image and use it in an if statement? corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

in my game the player is supposed to die when it goes out of bounds downwards, i have implemented physics and I would like to know how to get the current Y of my player and use it in an if statement sorta like this

> if player.y == display.contentHeight+100 then
>     endGame()
>   end

Comment: You can use your player image.y your code is correct, by the way, in corona SDK, player.y returns the middle of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the below statement

```
h=display.contentHeight
```

Hence create a Runtime eventlistener

```
local function RTListener(event)
     if player.y>h then
        endGame()
     end
 end
Runtime:addEventListener("Runtime",RTListener)
```

It will ends the game, when player goes out of bounds..